# Angular "scheduler.schedule is not a function" using observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm having an issue with an observable :

In a service I have a function (in edit.component):

```
public patchOne(entity: Tier): Observable<any> {

    const userData: any = this.httpService.getDataFromLocalStorage(AuthService.LOCAL_STORAGE_USER_TAG);

    return this.httpService.patch(`/someurl/${entity.uid}`, {
      params: {
        user_uid: JSON.parse(userData).userUId,
      },
      body: entity.createPatchTier(),
    }).map((res: any) => {
      // TODO : to complete
      return {};
    }).catch((error: any) => Observable.throw('patchOne - ', error.json().errorMessage || 'Server error'));
  }
```

Calling it from component (in edit.component):

```
  onSave() {
    if (this.validateFormData()) {
      this.tierService.patchOne(this._item).subscribe(() => {
        this.appCommunicationService.valid('Success');
      }, (error: any) => {
        this.appCommunicationService.error(error.message);
      });
    } else {
      this.appCommunicationService.info('Fail');
    }
  }
```

Triggered from a button with this property (ViewComponent.html):

```
(click)="component.onSave()"
```

I'm having this error uppon clicking :

```
ERROR TypeError: scheduler.schedule is not a function
    at ErrorObservable.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/observable/ErrorObservable.js.ErrorObservable._subscribe (ErrorObservable.js:72)
[...]
webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/components/edit/edit.component.ts.EditTiersComponent.onSave @   edit.component.ts:99
(anonymous) @   ViewComponent.html:14
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you have an error on this line:

```
.catch((error: any) => Observable.throw('patchOne - ', error.json().errorMessage || 'Server error'));
```

The [`Observable.throw`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-throw) has the following signature:

```
public static throw(error: any, scheduler: Scheduler): Observable
```

As you can see, the 2nd parameter is the `scheduler`. In your code, you're providing this 2nd parameter, so ultimately RxJs is trying to invoke `schedule` on your string (`error.json().errorMessage || 'Server error'`).

You need to update your error message to use string concatenation. e.g.:

```
'patchOne - ' + (error.json().errorMessage || 'Server error'))
```

Or perhaps using string interpolation:

```
`patchOne - ${(error.json().errorMessage || 'Server error')}`
```